# longtblr (longtablearray) spread over two-columns page

Tags: luatex, longtable

I'd like to ask how how make my longtablearray(longtblr) spread accross the two columns of the text (it's a 2-column paper, and I'd like my longtablearray to spread to fit the page width. thank you so much in advance.

Here's my minimal working example in overleaf: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y0xgthxh7ov26kh/exemplo%20simples%20pra%20stackoverflow.tex.txt?dl=0

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\spread{\textwidth}%%pra tabela ocupar 2 colunas do artigo
\caption{As 32 heurísticas propostas para avaliação de jogos educacionais para aprendizado da Língua Japonesa.}
\label{tab:tabela1}
\small
\centering
\noindent
\begin{longtblr}{hlines, vlines, colspec = {X[0.15, c] X[0.15, c] X[0.1, c] X[0.4, c] X[0.3, c]}} %% essa tabela tem 5 colunas (os 5 Xs, e cada um tem um tamanho relativo, e.g. 0,15
\SetCell[r=2]{c} Dimensão do fluxo
    &  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Componente do Framework             
        &   \SetCell[c=3]{c} Heurística             \\  
    & & Num. & Descrição detalhada & Referências CALL   \\
    \SetCell[r=3]{c} Equilíbrio de desafio e Habilidade & Adequação com o Estudante & 1 & Em cada fase de jogo, apresentar níveis adequados de novos termos e termos previamente introduzidos à estudantes, de forma que o estudante aprendiz não se sinta sobrecarregado com novos termos para memorizar. & [Ciampa, 2014; Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014] \\
    & Descrição Operacional & 2 & Proporcionar experiências novas ao refazer exercícios de jogo (e.g., eventos aleatórios baseados em sorte), de forma a proporcionar um desafio novo ao aprendiz enquanto ele revisa o que estudou previamente. &  [Macedonia, 2005; Xu et al., 2020] \\
    & Adequação com o Estudante & 3 & Criar comportamento como-humano acreditável para adversários não-jogadores, capaz de se adaptar de acordo com a habilidade cognitiva do estudante, cometer erros de forma similar ao estudante, e facilitar experiências de fluxo. No caso de exercícios online entre estudantes, utilizar algoritmos complexos para juntar estudantes de níveis similares de proficiência na língua.  &  [Ang e Zaphiris, 2008; Kacetl e Klímová, 2019; Kukulska-Hulme e Traxler, 2013; Macedonia, 2005;  Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014;  Traxler, 2009; Xu et al., 2020]\\
     \SetCell[r=4]{c} Objetivos Claros & Descrição Operacional  & 4 & Apresentar objetivos alcançáveis (em relação ao tempo gasto para aprender e exercitar um conteúdo da segunda língua). & [Kukulska-Hulme e Traxler, 2013; Traxler, 2009]\\
     & Adequação com o Estudante &  5   & Apresentar objetivos alcançáveis (em relação à dificuldade), considerando o nível de proficiência na língua do estudante. & [Kukulska-Hulme e Traxler, 2013; Traxler, 2009]\\
     & Adequação com o Estudante &  6 & Apresentar contextos reais de uso do conteúdo ensinado, de forma que fique claro para o estudante que ele está aprendendo m conteúdo envolvendo problemas de mundo real relevantes e interessantes para ele. &  [Butler, Someya e Fukuhara, 2014; Kukulska-Hulme e Traxler, 2013; Macedonia, 2005; Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014; Traxler, 2009]\\
     & Adequação com o Estudante    & 7 & Apresentar feedback de erro ao estudante de forma positiva, de forma que ele continue acreditando que aprender a segunda língua é um objetivo alcançável. & [Butler, Someya e Fukuhara, 2014; Ciampa, 2014]\\
      \SetCell[r=4]{c} Feedback Não-Ambíguo & Descrição Operacional, Adequação com o Professor  & 8 & Quando o estudante errar questões, oferecer feedback que não só apresente que a questão foi errada como apresente dicas para memorização da resposta correta, e explicações (de preferência trazendo contextos reais) que auxiliem no entendimento do erro, e promovam o raciocínio da compreensão do erro. & [Sykes, 2018; Xu et al., 2020]\\
      & Adequação com o Estudante   & 9 & Durante o ensino, oferecer dicas que auxiliem o estudante a lembrar da tradução de termos na segunda língua. &    [Xu et al., 2020]\\
      & Adequação com o Estudante   & 10    & Incentivar o estudante a compor suas próprias associações entre palavras da língua estrangeira e suas traduções. Também é recomendado que estudantes possam compartilhar associações criadas entre si, promovendo cooperação nos estudos. &   [Ciampa, 2014;  Kacetl e Klímová, 2019; Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014; Xu et al., 2020]\\
      & Descrição Operacional   & 11    & Evitar o excesso de texto. É recomendado o uso de outras mídias para explicação, como figuras, animações e áudio. & [Ciampa, 2014; Xu et al., 2020]\\
      \SetCell[r=2]{c} Junção de Ação e Percepção & Descrição Operacional   & 12 &  Apresentar objetivos e mecânicas de jogo simples, de forma a permitir que jogar o jogo seja algo espontâneo e automático, enquanto o conteúdo educacional relacionado às tarefas do jogador é conscientemente processado e refletido.   & [Macedonia, 2005; Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014]\\
      & Descrição Operacional   & 13 &  Evitar o excesso de comandos disponíveis em menus e ações de jogo disponíveis durante o jogo, de forma a facilitar a automatização de ações de jogo. &  [Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014]\\
      \SetCell[r=3]{c} Foco na tarefa & Descrição Operacional   & 14    & Apresentar elementos audiovisuais de forma atraente, e contextualizado com elementos culturais da segunda língua. & [Butler, Someya e Fukuhara, 2014; Ciampa, 2014;   Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014]\\
      & Descrição Operacional   & 15    & Elementos de jogo não podem distrair o jogador de seu objetivo principal no uso da ferramenta, que é aprender a segunda língua.   & [Butler, Someya e Fukuhara, 2014; Kacetl e Klímová, 2019]\\
      & Descrição Operacional   & 16    & Apresentar uma narrativa envolvente e com elementos culturais do país de origem da segunda língua. &  [Ang e Zaphiris, 2008; Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014; Sykes, 2018]
    
\end{longtblr}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your minimal working example, please? Have you written anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Long tables should not be enclosed in floating environment, If it is (as is in your case), it will not break at end of page bur protrude below it.
- That your table can be spreads over both columns, you need to interrupt two column by `\onecolumn` command text and after table with `\twocolumn` return back to two column document, At this should be aware, that those commands start new pages.

Possible solution:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
% text before table in two columns 

\onecolumn    % switch to one column, start new page!
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {As 32 heurísticas propostas para avaliação de jogos educacionais para aprendizado da Língua Japonesa.},
  label = {tab:tabela1}
                ]{hlines, vlines, 
                  colsep=4pt,
                  colspec = {X[c] X[c] c 
                             X[3.5, cmd=\RaggedRight] X[2, l]},
                  rows = {font=\small\linespread{0.9}\selectfont},
                  rowhead = 2
                  } %
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Dimensão do fluxo
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    Comp. do Framework
        &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    Heurística 
            &   &                                           \\
    &   & Num. 
            & Descrição detalhada 
                & Referências CALL                          \\
\SetCell[r=3]{c} Equilíbrio de desafio e Habilidade 
    & Adequação com o Estudante 
        & 1 &   Em cada fase de jogo, apresentar níveis adequados de novos termos e termos previamente introduzidos à estudantes, de forma que o estudante aprendiz não se sinta sobrecarregado com novos termos para memorizar. 
            &   [Ciampa, 2014; Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014]   \\
    & Descrição Operacional 
        & 2 &   Proporcionar experiências novas ao refazer exercícios de jogo (e.g., eventos aleatórios baseados em sorte), de forma a proporcionar um desafio novo ao aprendiz enquanto ele revisa o que estudou previamente. 
            &  [Macedonia, 2005; 
                Xu et al., 2020]                            \\
    & Adequação com o Estudante 
        & 3 &   Criar comportamento como-humano acreditável para adversários não-jogadores, capaz de se adaptar de acordo com a habilidade cognitiva do estudante, cometer erros de forma similar ao estudante, e facilitar experiências de fluxo. No caso de exercícios online entre estudantes, utilizar algoritmos complexos para juntar estudantes de níveis similares de proficiência na língua.  
            &   [Ang e Zaphiris, 2008;
                 Kacetl e Klímová, 2019;
                 Kukulska-Hulme e Traxler, 2013; 
                 Macedonia, 2005; 
                 Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014; 
                 Traxler, 2009; 
                 Xu et al., 2020]                           \\
\SetCell[r=4]{c} Objetivos Claros 
    &   Descrição Operacional  
        & 4 &   Apresentar objetivos alcançáveis (em relação ao tempo gasto para aprender e exercitar um conteúdo da segunda língua). 
                &   [Kukulska-Hulme e Traxler, 2013; 
                     Traxler, 2009]                         \\
    &   Adequação com o Estudante 
        & 5 & Apresentar objetivos alcançáveis (em relação à dificuldade), considerando o nível de proficiência na língua do estudante. 
                &   [Kukulska-Hulme e Traxler, 2013; 
                     Traxler, 2009]                         \\
     & Adequação com o Estudante 
        & 6 &   Apresentar contextos reais de uso do conteúdo ensinado, de forma que fique claro para o estudante que ele está aprendendo m conteúdo envolvendo problemas de mundo real relevantes e interessantes para ele. 
                &   [Butler, Someya e Fukuhara, 2014; 
                     Kukulska-Hulme e Traxler, 2013; 
                     Macedonia, 2005; 
                     Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014; 
                     Traxler, 2009]                         \\
     & Adequação com o Estudante    
        & 7 &   Apresentar feedback de erro ao estudante de forma positiva, de forma que ele continue acreditando que aprender a segunda língua é um objetivo alcançável. 
                &   [Butler, Someya e Fukuhara, 2014; 
                     Ciampa, 2014]                          \\
\SetCell[r=4]{c} Feedback Não-Ambíguo 
    &   Descrição Operacional, Adequação com o Professor  
        & 8 &   Quando o estudante errar questões, oferecer feedback que não só apresente que a questão foi errada como apresente dicas para memorização da resposta correta, e explicações (de preferência trazendo contextos reais) que auxiliem no entendimento do erro, e promovam o raciocínio da compreensão do erro. 
                &   [Sykes, 2018; 
                     Xu et al., 2020]                       \\
    &   Adequação com o Estudante   
        & 9 &   Durante o ensino, oferecer dicas que auxiliem o estudante a lembrar da tradução de termos na segunda língua. 
                &    [Xu et al., 2020]                      \\
    & Adequação com o Estudante   
        &10 &   Incentivar o estudante a compor suas próprias associações entre palavras da língua estrangeira e suas traduções. Também é recomendado que estudantes possam compartilhar associações criadas entre si, promovendo cooperação nos estudos.
                &   [Ciampa, 2014;  
                     Kacetl e Klímová, 2019; 
                     Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014; 
                     Xu et al., 2020]                       \\
    &   Descrição Operacional   
        &11 & Evitar o excesso de texto. É recomendado o uso de outras mídias para explicação, como figuras, animações e áudio.
                &   [Ciampa, 2014; Xu et al., 2020]         \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c} Junção de Ação e Percepção 
    &   Descrição Operacional   
        &12 &   Apresentar objetivos e mecânicas de jogo simples, de forma a permitir que jogar o jogo seja algo espontâneo e automático, enquanto o conteúdo educacional relacionado às tarefas do jogador é conscientemente processado e refletido.   
                &   [Macedonia, 2005; 
                     Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014]             \\
    &   Descrição Operacional   
        &13 &   Evitar o excesso de comandos disponíveis em menus e ações de jogo disponíveis durante o jogo, de forma a facilitar a automatização de ações de jogo. 
                &  [Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014]              \\
\SetCell[r=3]{c} Foco na tarefa 
    &   Descrição Operacional   
        &14 &   Apresentar elementos audiovisuais de forma atraente, e contextualizado com elementos culturais da segunda língua. 
                &   [Butler, Someya e Fukuhara, 2014; 
                     Ciampa, 2014;   
                     Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014]             \\
    &   Descrição Operacional   
        &15 &   Elementos de jogo não podem distrair o jogador de seu objetivo principal no uso da ferramenta, que é aprender a segunda língua.   
                &   [Butler, Someya e Fukuhara, 2014; 
                     Kacetl e Klímová, 2019]                \\
    &   Descrição Operacional   
        &16 &   Apresentar uma narrativa envolvente e com elementos culturais do país de origem da segunda língua. 
                &   [Ang e Zaphiris, 2008; 
                     Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014; 
                     Sykes, 2018]
\end{longtblr}
\twocolumn   % switch back to two column text, start new page
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you after?

**Addendum:**

- Switching from two column document to one column and than back may introduce new problems: empty space before switching of column.
- This problem you can solve by manually split table in two parts, ich insert in successive `table*` floats and in the sond one use `\ContinuedFloat` command defined in `\caption` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

    \begin{table*}
    \centering
\caption{As 32 heurísticas propostas para avaliação de jogos educacionais para aprendizado da Língua Japonesa.},
\label {tab:tabela1}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, 
                  colsep=4pt,
                  colspec = {X[c] X[c] c 
                             X[3.5, cmd=\RaggedRight] X[2, l]},
                  rows = {font=\small\linespread{0.9}\selectfont},
                  rowhead = 2
                  } %
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Dimensão do fluxo
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    Comp. do Framework
        &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    Heurística 
            &   &                                           \\
    &   & Num. 
            & Descrição detalhada 
                & Referências CALL                          \\
\SetCell[r=3]{c} Equilíbrio de desafio e Habilidade 
    & Adequação com o Estudante 
        & 1 &   Em cada fase de jogo, apresentar níveis adequados de novos termos e termos previamente introduzidos à estudantes, de forma que o estudante aprendiz não se sinta sobrecarregado com novos termos para memorizar. 
            &   [Ciampa, 2014; Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014]   \\
    & Descrição Operacional 
        & 2 &   Proporcionar experiências novas ao refazer exercícios de jogo (e.g., eventos aleatórios baseados em sorte), de forma a proporcionar um desafio novo ao aprendiz enquanto ele revisa o que estudou previamente. 
            &  [Macedonia, 2005; 
                Xu et al., 2020]                            \\
    & Adequação com o Estudante 
        & 3 &   Criar comportamento como-humano acreditável para adversários não-jogadores, capaz de se adaptar de acordo com a habilidade cognitiva do estudante, cometer erros de forma similar ao estudante, e facilitar experiências de fluxo. No caso de exercícios online entre estudantes, utilizar algoritmos complexos para juntar estudantes de níveis similares de proficiência na língua.  
            &   [Ang e Zaphiris, 2008;
                 Kacetl e Klímová, 2019;
                 Kukulska-Hulme e Traxler, 2013; 
                 Macedonia, 2005; 
                 Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014; 
                 Traxler, 2009; 
                 Xu et al., 2020]                           \\
\SetCell[r=4]{c} Objetivos Claros 
    &   Descrição Operacional  
        & 4 &   Apresentar objetivos alcançáveis (em relação ao tempo gasto para aprender e exercitar um conteúdo da segunda língua). 
                &   [Kukulska-Hulme e Traxler, 2013; 
                     Traxler, 2009]                         \\
    &   Adequação com o Estudante 
        & 5 & Apresentar objetivos alcançáveis (em relação à dificuldade), considerando o nível de proficiência na língua do estudante. 
                &   [Kukulska-Hulme e Traxler, 2013; 
                     Traxler, 2009]                         \\
     & Adequação com o Estudante 
        & 6 &   Apresentar contextos reais de uso do conteúdo ensinado, de forma que fique claro para o estudante que ele está aprendendo m conteúdo envolvendo problemas de mundo real relevantes e interessantes para ele. 
                &   [Butler, Someya e Fukuhara, 2014; 
                     Kukulska-Hulme e Traxler, 2013; 
                     Macedonia, 2005; 
                     Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014; 
                     Traxler, 2009]                         \\
     & Adequação com o Estudante    
        & 7 &   Apresentar feedback de erro ao estudante de forma positiva, de forma que ele continue acreditando que aprender a segunda língua é um objetivo alcançável. 
                &   [Butler, Someya e Fukuhara, 2014; 
                     Ciampa, 2014]                          \\
    \end{tblr}
    
\footnotesize\hfill Continue on the next page
    \end{table*}

    \begin{table*}
    \ContinuedFloat
    \centering
\caption{As 32 heurísticas propostas para avaliação de jogos educacionais para aprendizado da Língua Japonesa. (Continue)},
\label {tab:tabela1}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                  colsep=4pt,
                  colspec = {X[c] X[c] c
                             X[3.5, cmd=\RaggedRight] X[2, l]},
                  rows = {font=\small\linespread{0.9}\selectfont},
                  rowhead = 2
                  } %
\SetCell[r=4]{c} Feedback Não-Ambíguo 
    &   Descrição Operacional, Adequação com o Professor  
        & 8 &   Quando o estudante errar questões, oferecer feedback que não só apresente que a questão foi errada como apresente dicas para memorização da resposta correta, e explicações (de preferência trazendo contextos reais) que auxiliem no entendimento do erro, e promovam o raciocínio da compreensão do erro. 
                &   [Sykes, 2018; 
                     Xu et al., 2020]                       \\
    &   Adequação com o Estudante   
        & 9 &   Durante o ensino, oferecer dicas que auxiliem o estudante a lembrar da tradução de termos na segunda língua. 
                &    [Xu et al., 2020]                      \\
    & Adequação com o Estudante   
        &10 &   Incentivar o estudante a compor suas próprias associações entre palavras da língua estrangeira e suas traduções. Também é recomendado que estudantes possam compartilhar associações criadas entre si, promovendo cooperação nos estudos.
                &   [Ciampa, 2014;  
                     Kacetl e Klímová, 2019; 
                     Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014; 
                     Xu et al., 2020]                       \\
    &   Descrição Operacional   
        &11 & Evitar o excesso de texto. É recomendado o uso de outras mídias para explicação, como figuras, animações e áudio.
                &   [Ciampa, 2014; Xu et al., 2020]         \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c} Junção de Ação e Percepção 
    &   Descrição Operacional   
        &12 &   Apresentar objetivos e mecânicas de jogo simples, de forma a permitir que jogar o jogo seja algo espontâneo e automático, enquanto o conteúdo educacional relacionado às tarefas do jogador é conscientemente processado e refletido.   
                &   [Macedonia, 2005; 
                     Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014]             \\
    &   Descrição Operacional   
        &13 &   Evitar o excesso de comandos disponíveis em menus e ações de jogo disponíveis durante o jogo, de forma a facilitar a automatização de ações de jogo. 
                &  [Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014]              \\
\SetCell[r=3]{c} Foco na tarefa 
    &   Descrição Operacional   
        &14 &   Apresentar elementos audiovisuais de forma atraente, e contextualizado com elementos culturais da segunda língua. 
                &   [Butler, Someya e Fukuhara, 2014; 
                     Ciampa, 2014;   
                     Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014]             \\
    &   Descrição Operacional   
        &15 &   Elementos de jogo não podem distrair o jogador de seu objetivo principal no uso da ferramenta, que é aprender a segunda língua.   
                &   [Butler, Someya e Fukuhara, 2014; 
                     Kacetl e Klímová, 2019]                \\
    &   Descrição Operacional   
        &16 &   Apresentar uma narrativa envolvente e com elementos culturais do país de origem da segunda língua. 
                &   [Ang e Zaphiris, 2008; 
                     Robert Godwin-Jones, 2014; 
                     Sykes, 2018]
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks for the addendum answer! the text really becomes prettier this way! just one question though: how do you know when it's time to "split" the table into a new segment? It it trial and error?

Comment: @FabioPhillip, yes: trial and error, there is no other way as far as know.

Comment: thank you so much for your support, @Zarko ! just onee more question: during my split of the table in two parts (like the one you provided in the eaxmple), the table sequence is being numbered as a new table (like, table 4 being table 3 continuation). Is there any way that table 3 sequence keeps being numbered as table 3?

Comment: @FabioPhillip, do you insert `\ContinuedFloat` after each `\begin{table}`  following the first part of table?

Comment: oh! It was missing! many thanks again!