# What package or package combination to use for a multipage table with caption above the table and an automatically adjustable cell width?

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

Hi there my question is pretty much in the title. I have to create tables which are longer than one page. The caption needs to be above the table, it would also be a great extra option if i could rotate the text inside the cell and i would need an automatically adjustable cell width just like tabularX does. Do you have any recommendations?

Thank you

Comment: There is longtblr, but I can't seem to locate the manual.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675637/longtblr-longtablearray-spread-over-two-columns-page for exapml;e.